# java.lang.NullPointerException at com.sun.faces.application.resource.ResourceHandlerImpl.<init>(ResourceHandlerImpl.java:91)

Tags: maven, jsf, websphere

The project is working fine in tomcat, but when I start it in Websphere, it gives me the following error (Installation is successful).

What to do?

`pom.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 
  http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>SATYA_Parent</groupId>
        <artifactId>SATYA_Parent</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>
    <groupId>SATYA_Parent</groupId>
    <artifactId>SATYA_WAR</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>SATYA_WAR Maven Webapp</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

    <build>
        <finalName>SATYA_WAR</finalName>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
            </resource>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/lib</directory>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
            </resource>
            <resource>
                <targetPath>META-INF</targetPath>
                <directory>src/main/java/META-INF</directory>
                <includes>
                    <include>persistence.xml</include>
                </includes>
            </resource>
        </resources>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.6</source>
                    <target>1.6</target>
                    <encoding>ISO-8859-1</encoding>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.atlassian.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-clover2-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.5</version>
                <configuration>
                    <jdk>1.6</jdk>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.2</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.5</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
           <groupId>org.apache.openejb</groupId>
           <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
           <version>6.0-3</version>
           <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.6</version>
           <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency> 
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-impl</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.6</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- For Java EE Application Server, uncomment this library 
        and comment the rest of the libraries -->

        <!-- Oracle Mojarra APIs -->
        <!-- <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.faces</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsf-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency> -->
    <!-- Apache MyFaces APIs -->

    <!--        <dependency> -->
    <!--            <groupId>org.apache.myfaces.core</groupId> -->
    <!--            <artifactId>myfaces-api</artifactId> -->
    <!--            <version>2.0.11</version>            -->
    <!--        </dependency> -->
    <!--         <dependency> -->
    <!--             <groupId>org.apache.myfaces.core</groupId> -->
    <!--             <artifactId>myfaces-impl</artifactId> -->
    <!--             <version>2.0.11</version> -->
    <!--         </dependency> -->

        <!-- For Servlet Container like Tomcat -->
        <!-- http://download.java.net/maven/2 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsf-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.0-b03</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsf-impl</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.0-b03</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- EL 2.2 to support method parameter in EL -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.web</groupId>
            <artifactId>el-impl</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- http://repo1.maven.org/maven -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- The following jars need not be packaged. Hence optional=true -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-collections</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-collections</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <!--4. End of Calypso dependencies-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.14</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- MOCKEJB DEPENDENCIES -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockejb</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockejb</artifactId>
            <version>0.6-beta2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-all</artifactId>
            <version>1.8.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Database Drivers -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.60</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
            <artifactId>ojdbc14</artifactId>
            <version>10.2.0.2.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>java.net.m2</id>
            <name>java.net m2 repo</name>
            <url>http://download.java.net/maven/2</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
</project>
```

Stack trace:

```
[5/22/15 13:15:25:602 IST] 000000a8 config        I   Initializing Mojarra 2.1.0 (SNAPSHOT 20100817) for context '/SATYA_WAR'
[5/22/15 13:15:26:219 IST] 000000a8 config        I   Unsanitized stacktrace from failed start...
                                 com.sun.faces.config.ConfigurationException:
  Source Document: wsjar:file:/opt/WebSphere/AppServer/profiles/vm4/installedApps/SOL/SATYA_EAR.ear/SATYA_WAR-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war/WEB-INF/lib/jsf-impl-2.1.0-b03.jar!/com/sun/faces/jsf-ri-runtime.xml
  Cause: Unable to create a new instance of 'com.sun.faces.application.resource.ResourceHandlerImpl': java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.sun.faces.config.processor.AbstractConfigProcessor.createInstance(AbstractConfigProcessor.java:289)
        at com.sun.faces.config.processor.ApplicationConfigProcessor.setResourceHandler(ApplicationConfigProcessor.java:748)
        at com.sun.faces.config.processor.ApplicationConfigProcessor.process(ApplicationConfigProcessor.java:306)
        at com.sun.faces.config.processor.AbstractConfigProcessor.invokeNext(AbstractConfigProcessor.java:110)
        at com.sun.faces.config.processor.LifecycleConfigProcessor.process(LifecycleConfigProcessor.java:112)
        at com.sun.faces.config.processor.AbstractConfigProcessor.invokeNext(AbstractConfigProcessor.java:110)
        at com.sun.faces.config.processor.FactoryConfigProcessor.process(FactoryConfigProcessor.java:212)
        at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigManager.initialize(ConfigManager.java:332)
        at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener.contextInitialized(ConfigureListener.java:222)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.notifyServletContextCreated(WebApp.java:1686)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppImpl.initialize(WebAppImpl.java:410)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebGroupImpl.addWebApplication(WebGroupImpl.java:88)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.VirtualHostImpl.addWebApplication(VirtualHostImpl.java:169)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.addWebApp(WSWebContainer.java:749)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.addWebApplication(WSWebContainer.java:634)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.component.WebContainerImpl.install(WebContainerImpl.java:422)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.component.WebContainerImpl.start(WebContainerImpl.java:714)
        at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.start(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:1164)
        at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedApplicationImpl.fireDeployedObjectStart(DeployedApplicationImpl.java:1369)
        at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedModuleImpl.start(DeployedModuleImpl.java:639)
        at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedApplicationImpl.start(DeployedApplicationImpl.java:967)
        at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.startApplication(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:770)
        at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.startApplicationDynamically(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:1361)
        at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.start(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:2162)
        at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.start(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:446)
        at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitImpl.start(CompositionUnitImpl.java:123)
        at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.start(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:389)
        at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.access$500(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:117)
        at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl$1.run(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:664)
        at com.ibm.ws.security.auth.ContextManagerImpl.runAs(ContextManagerImpl.java:5468)
        at com.ibm.ws.security.auth.ContextManagerImpl.runAsSystem(ContextManagerImpl.java:5594)
        at com.ibm.ws.security.core.SecurityContext.runAsSystem(SecurityContext.java:255)
        at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.startCompositionUnit(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:678)
        at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.startCompositionUnit(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:622)
        at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.startApplication(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:1251)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:60)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:611)
        at sun.reflect.misc.Trampoline.invoke(MethodUtil.java:69)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:60)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:611)
        at sun.reflect.misc.MethodUtil.invoke(MethodUtil.java:272)
        at javax.management.modelmbean.RequiredModelMBean$4.run(RequiredModelMBean.java:1152)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:298)
        at com.ibm.oti.security.CheckedAccessControlContext.securityCheck(CheckedAccessControlContext.java:30)
        at sun.misc.JavaSecurityAccessWrapper.doIntersectionPrivilege(JavaSecurityAccessWrapper.java:41)
        at javax.management.modelmbean.RequiredModelMBean.invokeMethod(RequiredModelMBean.java:1146)
        at javax.management.modelmbean.RequiredModelMBean.invoke(RequiredModelMBean.java:999)
        at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:847)
        at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:783)
        at com.ibm.ws.management.AdminServiceImpl$1.run(AdminServiceImpl.java:1335)
        at com.ibm.ws.security.util.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:118)
        at com.ibm.ws.management.AdminServiceImpl.invoke(AdminServiceImpl.java:1228)
        at com.ibm.ws.management.connector.AdminServiceDelegator.invoke(AdminServiceDelegator.java:181)
        at com.ibm.ws.management.connector.ipc.CallRouter.route(CallRouter.java:247)
        at com.ibm.ws.management.connector.ipc.IPCConnectorInboundLink.doWork(IPCConnectorInboundLink.java:360)
        at com.ibm.ws.management.connector.ipc.IPCConnectorInboundLink$IPCConnectorReadCallback.complete(IPCConnectorInboundLink.java:602)
        at com.ibm.ws.ssl.channel.impl.SSLReadServiceContext$SSLReadCompletedCallback.complete(SSLReadServiceContext.java:1819)
        at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted(AioReadCompletionListener.java:175)
        at com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:217)
        at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncChannelFuture.fireCompletionActions(AsyncChannelFuture.java:161)
        at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncFuture.completed(AsyncFuture.java:138)
        at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.complete(ResultHandler.java:204)
        at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.runEventProcessingLoop(ResultHandler.java:775)
        at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler$2.run(ResultHandler.java:905)
        at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1702)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.sun.faces.application.resource.ResourceHandlerImpl.<init>(ResourceHandlerImpl.java:91)
        at java.lang.J9VMInternals.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1563)
        at com.sun.faces.config.processor.AbstractConfigProcessor.createInstance(AbstractConfigProcessor.java:264)
        ... 68 more

[5/22/15 13:15:26:222 IST] 000000a8 config        E   Critical error during deployment:
                                 com.sun.faces.config.ConfigurationException: CONFIGURATION FAILED! null
        at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigManager.initialize(ConfigManager.java:351)
        at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener.contextInitialized(ConfigureListener.java:222)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.notifyServletContextCreated(WebApp.java:1686)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppImpl.initialize(WebAppImpl.java:410)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebGroupImpl.addWebApplication(WebGroupImpl.java:88)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.VirtualHostImpl.addWebApplication(VirtualHostImpl.java:169)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.addWebApp(WSWebContainer.java:749)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.addWebApplication(WSWebContainer.java:634)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.component.WebContainerImpl.install(WebContainerImpl.java:422)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.component.WebContainerImpl.start(WebContainerImpl.java:714)
        at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.start(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:1164)
        at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedApplicationImpl.fireDeployedObjectStart(DeployedApplicationImpl.java:1369)
        at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedModuleImpl.start(DeployedModuleImpl.java:639)
        at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedApplicationImpl.start(DeployedApplicationImpl.java:967)
        at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.startApplication(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:770)
        at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.startApplicationDynamically(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:1361)
        at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.start(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:2162)
        at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.start(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:446)
        at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitImpl.start(CompositionUnitImpl.java:123)
        at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.start(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:389)
        at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.access$500(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:117)
        at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl$1.run(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:664)
        at com.ibm.ws.security.auth.ContextManagerImpl.runAs(ContextManagerImpl.java:5468)
        at com.ibm.ws.security.auth.ContextManagerImpl.runAsSystem(ContextManagerImpl.java:5594)
        at com.ibm.ws.security.core.SecurityContext.runAsSystem(SecurityContext.java:255)
        at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.startCompositionUnit(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:678)
        at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.startCompositionUnit(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:622)
        at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.startApplication(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:1251)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:60)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:611)
        at sun.reflect.misc.Trampoline.invoke(MethodUtil.java:69)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:60)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:611)
        at sun.reflect.misc.MethodUtil.invoke(MethodUtil.java:272)
        at javax.management.modelmbean.RequiredModelMBean$4.run(RequiredModelMBean.java:1152)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:298)
        at com.ibm.oti.security.CheckedAccessControlContext.securityCheck(CheckedAccessControlContext.java:30)
        at sun.misc.JavaSecurityAccessWrapper.doIntersectionPrivilege(JavaSecurityAccessWrapper.java:41)
        at javax.management.modelmbean.RequiredModelMBean.invokeMethod(RequiredModelMBean.java:1146)
        at javax.management.modelmbean.RequiredModelMBean.invoke(RequiredModelMBean.java:999)
        at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:847)
        at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:783)
        at com.ibm.ws.management.AdminServiceImpl$1.run(AdminServiceImpl.java:1335)
        at com.ibm.ws.security.util.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:118)
        at com.ibm.ws.management.AdminServiceImpl.invoke(AdminServiceImpl.java:1228)
        at com.ibm.ws.management.connector.AdminServiceDelegator.invoke(AdminServiceDelegator.java:181)
        at com.ibm.ws.management.connector.ipc.CallRouter.route(CallRouter.java:247)
        at com.ibm.ws.management.connector.ipc.IPCConnectorInboundLink.doWork(IPCConnectorInboundLink.java:360)
        at com.ibm.ws.management.connector.ipc.IPCConnectorInboundLink$IPCConnectorReadCallback.complete(IPCConnectorInboundLink.java:602)
        at com.ibm.ws.ssl.channel.impl.SSLReadServiceContext$SSLReadCompletedCallback.complete(SSLReadServiceContext.java:1819)
        at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted(AioReadCompletionListener.java:175)
        at com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:217)
        at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncChannelFuture.fireCompletionActions(AsyncChannelFuture.java:161)
        at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncFuture.completed(AsyncFuture.java:138)
        at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.complete(ResultHandler.java:204)
        at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.runEventProcessingLoop(ResultHandler.java:775)
        at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler$2.run(ResultHandler.java:905)
        at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1702)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.sun.faces.application.resource.ResourceHandlerImpl.<init>(ResourceHandlerImpl.java:91)
        at java.lang.J9VMInternals.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1563)
        at com.sun.faces.config.processor.AbstractConfigProcessor.createInstance(AbstractConfigProcessor.java:264)
        at com.sun.faces.config.processor.ApplicationConfigProcessor.setResourceHandler(ApplicationConfigProcessor.java:748)
        at com.sun.faces.config.processor.ApplicationConfigProcessor.process(ApplicationConfigProcessor.java:306)
        at com.sun.faces.config.processor.AbstractConfigProcessor.invokeNext(AbstractConfigProcessor.java:110)
        at com.sun.faces.config.processor.LifecycleConfigProcessor.process(LifecycleConfigProcessor.java:112)
        at com.sun.faces.config.processor.AbstractConfigProcessor.invokeNext(AbstractConfigProcessor.java:110)
        at com.sun.faces.config.processor.FactoryConfigProcessor.process(FactoryConfigProcessor.java:212)
        at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigManager.initialize(ConfigManager.java:332)
        ... 61 more
```

`web.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
    <display-name>KDDI- Web Application</display-name>


    <welcome-file-list>
            <welcome-file>configurationClass.xhtml</welcome-file>
        </welcome-file-list>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.fmt.localizationContext</param-name>
        <param-value>resources.application</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <description>State saving method: 'client' or 'server' (=default). See JSF Specification 2.5.2</description>
        <param-name>javax.faces.STATE_SAVING_METHOD</param-name>
        <param-value>client</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
        <param-value>Development</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.jsf</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.faces</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
</web-app>
```

Comment: Add your web.xml, looks like you are missing `<listener-class>com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener</listener-class>`

Comment: Either remove JSF implementation (`SATYA_EAR.ear/SATYA_WAR-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war/WEB-INF/lib/jsf-impl-2.1.0-b03.jar`) from your app and use one provided by WebSphere, or configure your application to use third party JSF - [Configuring JavaServer Faces implementation](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.nd.doc/ae/tweb_jsf.html?cp=SSAW57_8.5.5%2F1-13-2-33-0-2-3&lang=en)

Comment: How to use mojarra provided by websphere? Do i need to configure anything in pom.xml?

Comment: That configure listener is completely unnecessary. It's only relevant as a workaround to a prehistoric GlassFish v3 bug (which was already fixed in 3.1). That some IDEs stubbornly still include them in the autogenerated web.xml is indeed unfortunate as it only causes confusion among starters like Kenneth Clark.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is caused by the fact that Tomcat is a barebones Java servlet container, and that WebSphere is a full fledged Java EE application server.

The major difference is that a servlet container only offers the following parts of the Java EE API out the box:

- Servlet
- JSP
- EL

A servlet container doesn't ship with JSTL, JSF out the box (let alone EJB, JMS, JPA, etc). That was exactly why you had to explicitly provide them along with the webapp, as done via your `pom.xml` (as there's even a comment indicating that, it seems that you copypasted the pom or used some kickoff project and actually didn't wrote (or even read or understood) that comment yourself).

A Java EE application server, however, offers them all out the box. When you still provide e.g. JSF along with the webapp, then it will only conflict with server-bundled JSF, resulting in internal initialization erros like this.

You **must** set `<scope>provided</scope>` on the dependencies which are already provided by the target server (and your webapp isn't configured in such way that the webapp-bundled dependencies should take precedence in loading).